# updating command line parameters in batch file

Tags: batch-file

**Batch file **I am writing batch file that takes in command line parameters and do some stuff if the parameters match. But when the run the batch file again with the new parameters, the file still runs with the old parameters.

1. first run : file.bat -name hello -w 400 -r 320
2. second run : file.bat -name hello -w 400.

When i do the second run of the file, it still performs the first run, i mean to say it still considers the parameters from the first run. Does anybody know why this is the case?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for not posting the batch file code.
below mentioned is the code.

```
set filename= 
set rate=
set hidden=
set rate=
:recheck 
if  "%1"=="-help"  goto :help
if  "%1"=="-name"  goto :filename
if  "%1"=="-h"     goto :hidden 
if  "%1"=="-w"     goto :weight 
if  "%1"=="-r"     goto :rate 
if  "%~1"==""      goto :endofcommandline
:filename 
shift 
set filename =%1
shift   
goto :recheck
```

For the other part of the file, I use the variable "filename" to do other stuff. I also use setlocal and endlocal at the beginning and the end of the file.
I have other corresponding labels for the each if statement and set different variables to the values passed to them if any by the user. 
Sometimes, I also get echo is off when I try to print out the value of some variable.
All the variables which I use are cleared in the beginning of the file as mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you don't show the batch file, how in the world do you expect us to know what's wrong with it? We can't see your screen or read your mind from here; all we know is what you provide in your question. If you don't tell us, we can't help. Please edit your question and provide the batch content, or I'd suspect this question will be closed pretty quickly as "not a real question". You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); there's info in there about how to ask a better question in order to improve your chances of getting an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: BTW, the chances are good (just guessing, though) that the first run sets up environmental variables that aren't cleared at the end of the run, and so the second run inherits the ones that aren't changed (the `-r 300`, in the examples you gave). It would be a better guess if you posted the batch file itself, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple points here.

> "I also use setlocal and endlocal at the beginning and the end of the file."
>
> "All the variables which I use are cleared in the beginning of the file as mentioned above."

Setlocal command does *NOT clear* the variables, it *preserve* current variables from posterior modification. This mean that if in a previous execution of your Batch file, or even via typed SET commands, filename variable was defined, it value remains until it is deleted or modified.

"Ok!", you said, "filename variable is modified the second time the Batch file run, Right?"

Well, no... The following line:

```
set filename =%1
```

does NOT modify "filename" variable, but "filename " instead (filename and a space). Try this:

```
set filename=No space
echo %filename%
set filename =Bad name with trailing space
echo %filename %
echo %filename%
```

You must carefully check your program to avoid this type of errors.